# Running Local disk media file in Wowza media server

Tags: wowza

Is there a way to specify the streaming video file location other the path which is the child directory of the home directory in which Wowza is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
Go to conf directory:

```
Wowza Media Server 3.5.0\conf\live\Application.xml
```

Locate this part of the file:

```
<Streams>
    <StreamType>live</StreamType>
    <StorageDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/content</StorageDir>
```

User **StorageDir** to specify you files location, for example:

```
<StorageDir>/usr/home/video</StorageDir>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any local or network directories : 
example : C:\yourwowzacontentdirextory